# R desconsiderando um data_frame na Function

Tags: r, funções, dataset

Estou trabalhando para automatizar um processo de manipulação de dados que tenho aqui na minha demanda pessoal no trabalho.
Criei uma function que abre as bases de dados de todos os anos que tenho vendas, o intuito é juntá-las para depois manipular os dados e posteriormente exportar como excel para alimentar o dashboard no Power BI. Juntando todas as bases de dados somam 122.651 linhas, porém depois que a function roda inteira, ela gera um dataset com 122.553 linhas (o que corresponde às somas de 2017 até 2021, ignorando o dataset de 2022).

[image: Segue print]

Comment: A função está mal definida, tente `f<-function(){ o seu código de leitura, join e return }` seguido de `base_ok <- f()`.

Answer (score 1):

Tente a seguinte função.

```
ler_ficheiros <- function(anos, path = "."){
  pattern <- paste0("^", anos, ".xls")
  pattern <- paste(pattern, collapse = "|")
  fich <- list.files(path = path, pattern = pattern, full.names = TRUE)
  df_list <- lapply(fich, read_excel)
  base_actual <- Reduce(full_join, df_list)
  base_actual
}

base_ok <- ler_ficheiros(2017:2022)
dim(base_ok)
```